# IOS Google Analytics - no data coming through

Tags: ios, google-analytics-sdk

I have 2 iOS apps which I am trying to connect to google analytics. One of them is working, the other is not!

The one which is working has been published for a couple of years now. The one that is not working is a new app, but uses the same code - just different graphics & data.

In the log, the only difference I can see is (the app which is working):

```
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:]
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:208): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200
```

The app which isn't working shows:

```
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:]
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:208): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status -1
```

As far as I can tell, the set up on GA side is identical, and both apps use the same files for code. Also the request seems to be the same, apart from the app id and UA key - which are correct:

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:]
(GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:497): Saved hit: {
parameters =     {
    "&_crc" = 0;
    "&_u" = ".etno";
    "&_v" = "mi3.1.0";
    "&a" = 53345067;
    "&aid" = "com.mycompany.myapp";
    "&an" = Recipes;
    "&av" = "2.2";
    "&cd" = Recipes;
    "&cid" = "f2da689b-ebdb-4e9e-9370-b8150c9950f1";
    "&ds" = app;
    "&sr" = 320x568;
    "&t" = appview;
    "&tid" = "UA-56722604-1";
    "&ul" = "en-gb";
    "&v" = 1;
    "&z" = 2718623027941064481;
    gaiVersion = "3.10";
};
timestamp = "2014-11-14 11:33:17 +0000";
}
```

Any idea why I would be getting a -1 http status?

Thanks for looking.

***EDIT***

Having looked at this further, I am sometimes getting a 200 status in the app which is not working - I am guessing the -1 indicates a temporary network error (My internet connection has been pretty flaky this week!)

But even with the 200 response I still see no data in GA.

Comment: why is the HTTP status code "-1" thats not even a HTTP code. Very strange?

Comment: just try in another key

Comment: Already tried that - I have used the key from the app which is working, and then it works. I then tried creating a new key for the other app, but still the same.

Comment: I'm also getting the HTTP status -1, but my account's been open for months, and I created the ID at that time.  This is the first time in months I've tried to use the ID, however. And of course, the Real Time view shows nothing. GAI seems to think the transaction was successful though. 

I'm getting the same results on simulator and on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out it is actually working. However the 'real time' results are not working, and it took over 72 hours (from GA account creation) before results were seen in GA!

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but in the interest of helping someone else later on: from my research it seems that if there is only a single hit to send, GA will send it as a GET string with the vars as query string params. When it uses the GET, it's HTTP response is a -1, probably because it didn't actually make an API call.

If there are more than 1 hit queued up to send to the GA servers, it will use a POST call to the GA API. When this happens, the HTTP response is a 200.

Comment: Thanks for your input Ryan. That's a helpful insight into the interior workings of GA!

Comment: Thank you, couldn't find this answer anywhere else!

Comment: To expand on this explanation, the GET parameters are not being encoded properly, which is causing an error. In my case, attempting to send a comma-delimited custom dimension is causing the failure. I also noticed that putting a "/" character causes a failure.